# SQL query to find users with apps with no releases

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, exists

In my database, I have users, apps, and releases. A user can have 0..n apps through a permissions table and an app can have 0..n releases.

I'm trying to get a list of users who have at least 1 app, but none of that user's apps have any releases.

The schema is roughly

```
users  permissions  apps  releases
-----  -----------  ----  --------
id     user_id      id    id
email  app_id             app_id
```

I *think* I've got something working with this, but it appears inefficient to me because I mention the permissions table twice and I'm using nested exists clauses. Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

```
select u.email from users u 
    join permissions p on p.user_id = u.id 
    where not exists (
        select a.id from apps a 
            join permissions p on p.app_id = a.id 
            where p.user_id = u.id and exists (
                select r.id from releases r 
                    where r.app_id = a.id
            )
    );
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a `LEFT JOIN` on releases, and then look for the case where the number of released apps (r.app_id is non-NULL) is 0. If all you want is a list of users, I don't think you need to `JOIN` the `apps` table at all, as `JOIN`ing on `permissions` will ensure that only users that have permission for 1 or more apps are included.

```
SELECT u.email
FROM users u
JOIN permissions p ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN releases r ON r.app_id = p.app_id
GROUP BY u.email
HAVING COUNT(r.app_id) = 0
```

Comment: I was thinking on something like this at first, but suppose user A have permissions to APP1 and APP2, where APP1 have releases and APP2 don't have any releases. I think this user will be select but is contradictory to this: _but none of that user's apps have any releases_.

Comment: @D.Smania you're absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The first `Join` seems to be correct between `users` and `permissions` table. You just need to check whether the app_id from joined result-set exists in `releases` table or not. You can try this query -

```
select u.email from users u 
join permissions p on p.user_id = u.id 
where not exists ( Select 1 from releases r where r.App_id = p.app_id)
```

Comment: This will display a user who has permissions to APP1 and APP2 but only APP2 has been released, which does not meet the question criteria "**none** of that user's apps have any releases"

Answer (score 1):

I will do something like this, hope this helps:

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.email
FROM
    users AS u
INNER JOIN
    permissions AS p ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
    releases AS r ON r.app_id = p.app_id
GROUP BY
    u.id, u.email
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is a combination of left and inner joins like this:

```
Select
    email
From users u
Inner Join (
    Select
        p.user_id
        , p.app_id
     From permissions p
     Left Join releases r
        on p.app_id = r.app_id
     Where r.app_id is null) a
on u.user_id = a.user_id
Group by email
```

It's hard to tell which is faster between this and the previous posted solution without knowing the size of the different tables (and hence how many rows SQL will be trying to join).

One thing that is clear -  without the 'Group by email' line at the end, you might see users' email repeated multiple times in your list.  Generally, literature on SQL states that using a "group by" statement at the end of your query is a faster way to get a distinct set than a "select distinct" statement at the beginning of your query.